# Map wildcard subdomains to S3 static site folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Is there a way that, by using a mix of the AWS Cloudfront, S3 and Route 53 to set up a set of static websites in such a way that an indefinite number of subdomains (wildcard) are mapped to a single S3 bucket's folders?

Eg:

http://first.example.com maps to https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.com/first/index.html

http://second.example.com maps to https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.com/second/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, you can do it with Lambda@Edge functions.

First, map the wildcard (*) subdomain on Route53.

Then add the wildcard domain *.example.com to the alternate domain names in CloudFront

Write a Lambda function that changes the origin path based on the subdomain in the request.
See an example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/)

Comment: This sounds really, really interesting. Lambda@Edge is not something I heard about but will look into it.

Comment: is there any latest way ?

Comment: @anon Is there latest way ?